# Semantic search engines

Tags: search-engine, semantic-web

Are there any semantic search engines or information search engines out there that people has heard of? Of course Google is the biggest search engine right now. Other than Bing, Yahoo, Google, are there any semantic search engines that are interesting?

Comment: Such a recommendation question is off-topic here. -- If you can list specific features such a search engine should have, you could ask a question on [softwarerecs.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the most famous semantic search engine is Swoogle of umbc.

Also, you can find a comprehensive list of such SEs in (http://www.w3.org/wiki/TaskForces/CommunityProjects/LinkingOpenData/SemanticWebSearchEngines).

Moreover, in recent years, Google provides support for semantic search.

Answer (score 0):

My company IP Street provides a semantic patent search as an API service. Specifically, we use the a [latent semantic indexing algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_analysis). You send us raw text, we send you patents indexed from most to least conceptually similar.

Check it our API service here: http://docs.ipstreet.com/docs/concept-search

Comment: I am looking for a similar sematic search utility. I have a collection of text files and if I provide a phrase for the search, I need to get back sentences that contains the meaning of the phrase, ordered by ranking. e.g.: "physics work" should match sentence like "complete all your worksheets of physics". Can you suggest how to do it ?

Comment: Hi Hrishikesh,  There are some open source libraries that would allow you to do this in Python but it requires quite a bit of coding and DevOps work.  Alternatively, if you wanted a manage semantic search as a service, I would reach out to the guys at Foretheta.com.  It's kind of like Algolia, you just send them a corpus of documents and they do the rest, providing you with a RESTful api interface to search through.  You should email danial@foretheta.com.

Comment: I need to search local files, I am currently using fuzzy wuzzy and some lcs algorithm.

Comment: In that case, I would use Gensim.  It's a open source python library which will enable you to build a concept search engine on your local machine.  It's a little bit of overhead but doable for smaller corpses that will fit on your single machine.  It's really good. https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is a bit older, you might be interested in looking into [Weaviate](https://github.com/semi-technologies/weaviate).

Example of a semantic query from the [docs](https://www.semi.technology/documentation/weaviate/current/query-data/filters.html#explore-filter):

```
{
  Get{
    Things{
      Publication(
        explore: {
          concepts: ["fashion"],
          certainty: 0.7,
          moveAwayFrom: {
            concepts: ["finance"],
            force: 0.45
          },
          moveTo: {
            concepts: ["haute couture"],
            force: 0.85
          }
        }
      ){
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can also [try out](http://playground.semi.technology/?weaviate_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdemo.dataset.playground.semi.technology%2Fv1%2Fgraphql&graphiql&gqlquery=%7B%0D%0A++Get%7B%0D%0A++++Things%7B%0D%0A++++++Publication%28%0D%0A++++++++explore%3A+%7B%0D%0A++++++++++concepts%3A+%5B%22fashion%22%5D%2C%0D%0A++++++++++certainty%3A+0.7%2C%0D%0A++++++++++moveAwayFrom%3A+%7B%0D%0A++++++++++++concepts%3A+%5B%22finance%22%5D%2C%0D%0A++++++++++++force%3A+0.45%0D%0A++++++++++%7D%2C%0D%0A++++++++++moveTo%3A+%7B%0D%0A++++++++++++concepts%3A+%5B%22haute+couture%22%5D%2C%0D%0A++++++++++++force%3A+0.85%0D%0A++++++++++%7D%0D%0A++++++++%7D%0D%0A++++++%29%7B%0D%0A++++++++name%0D%0A++++++%7D%0D%0A++++%7D%0D%0A++%7D%0D%0A%7D) the query in real-time.